# Php Unit Testing not covering all the attributes label of Yii2 model

Tags: yii2, phpunit, code-coverage, yii2-basic-app

I am writing testing code for Yii2 When I am testing with phpunit. Then Code coverage check is not covering the attributes labels method totally. It only cover the first line of that. This is My Testing Model code given below.

```
public function testattributeLabels()
{
    $attribute = Academicrecords::attributeLabels();
    print_r($attribute);

    $this->assertInternalType('array',$attribute);
    $this->assertContains('Student Name',$attribute);

    $this->assertEquals('Student Name',$attribute['student_id']);
    $this->assertEquals('ID',$attribute['id']);
    $this->assertEquals('School Name',$attribute['school_name']);
    $this->assertEquals('Class',$attribute['class']);
    $this->assertEquals('Stream',$attribute['stream']);

    $this->assertEquals('Created On',$attribute['created_on']);
    $this->assertEquals('Modified On',$attribute['modified_on']);
    $this->assertEquals('Created By',$attribute['created_by']);
    $this->assertEquals('Modified By',$attribute['modified_by']);
}
```

This is my Model code

```
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'id' => 'ID',
        'student_id' => 'Student Name',
        'school_name' => 'School Name',
        'class' => 'Class',
        'stream' => 'Stream',
        'created_by' => 'Created By',
        'created_on' => 'Created On',
        'modified_by' => 'Modified By',
        'modified_on' => 'Modified On',
    ];
}
```

This is my codeception result
[This is my Codeception result code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CV8hs.png)

Answer (score 0):

Since attributeLabels() is not a static function, you might want to try this. Not sure if it solves your issue though.

```
public function testattributeLabels() {
    $model = new Academicrecords();

    $this->assertEquals('Student Name',$model->getAttributeLabel('student_id'));
    $this->assertEquals('ID',$model->getAttributeLabel('id'));
    $this->assertEquals('School Name',$model->getAttributeLabel('school_name'));
    $this->assertEquals('Class',$model->getAttributeLabel('class'));
    $this->assertEquals('Stream',$model->getAttributeLabel('stream'));

    $this->assertEquals('Created On',$model->getAttributeLabel('created_on'));
    $this->assertEquals('Modified On',$model->getAttributeLabel('modified_on'));
    $this->assertEquals('Created By',$model->getAttributeLabel('created_by'));
    $this->assertEquals('Modified By',$model->getAttributeLabel('modified_by')); 
}
```